# NLB - Multiple NLBs in EKS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-eks, nlb

I currently have a setup where I have 1 NLB in my EKS cluster. I deployed ServiceA and ServiceB and both of them use the same NLB.

However, I am curious to know whether it is possible to create more than 1 NLB in a EKS cluster?

- If yes, which use case would this be useful for?
- And how would I specify ServiceC to use NLB1 and ServiceD to use NLB2?

I did not find specific documentation surrounding this and any pointers on this would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Use case? multi-tenancy - multiple sites or customers sharing the cluster

Answer (score 2):

It is possible.

I've never done it with NLBs but this should be as simple as deploying a second `Service` of type `LoadBalancer` with the annotation indicating it's a nlb rather than an elb.

As to use case, a few that spring to mind:

1. strict requirements for segregation of traffic
2. namespacing of project resources

Routing would be accomplished by binding the deployment manifests for service C to the Service for NLB1 and the deployment manifests of service D to NLB2.  Services route to pods through selectors, so it's merely a matter of ensuring your mapping is correct.